# Building a Database Model for Role Based Access Control

Tags: sql, database, roles, rbac

I'm trying to make a role based access control system, but the problem comes when I approach the Database Part of It.

Should I make two models, Role and Permission, and then make a many to many relationship between role and permission or what?

My User Model looks something like this:

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |      Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
 id         | uuid                        |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 name       | character varying(50)       |           | not null |
 email      | character varying(320)      |           | not null |
 avatar     | text                        |           |          |
 password   | text                        |           | not null |
 phone      | character varying(30)       |           |          |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()
 companyId  | uuid                        |           |          |
 roleId     | uuid                        |           |          |
```

So I just have 1 to many relation ship between user and role.

Comment: In your use case, is there a one to one relationship between user and role?

Comment: One to many is there

Comment: In that case, maintain 3 different tables, first containing information regarding user, second containing all the master roles and third will contain mapping between users and roles i.e. many to many relationships.

Comment: Why aren't you using existing models? There are plenty of tools that implement rbac

Comment: Can you link me some?

Answer (score -1):

Mainly it's done with a single role and multiple users associated with it.
Roles can be assigned privileges and users can be assigned roles.
You can refer following for the same.
[Role-based access control in Postgres/mongo](https://medium.com/@tushargupta7/role-based-access-in-postgres-rbac-c51b8f797de9)